# Store tabular data on Swift

Tags: ios, swift

What kind of **data structure** should I use that would allow me **to store tabular data** (and append new data to it), as well as operate over it (calc aggregations, etc).

Specifically I'm looking for something similar to `pandas` (for python). Right now **I don't need to draw the data table** but, only to store data.

For example, imagine I want to append values to a table every 5 seconds, so that, every hour I will aggregate the information into a new data structure.

Comment: Have you checked this project?

https://github.com/siegesmund/dataframe

It's inspired by Pandas

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could help you?

```
struct Table<T>{
    typealias Columns = [T]
    typealias Rows = [Columns]
    private var data: Rows = []

    mutating func appendRow(row: Columns){
        data.append(row)
    }

    func getRow(index: Int) -> Columns?{
        return data[safe: index]
    }
}

var intTable = Table<Int>()
intTable.appendRow(row: [1,2,3,4])
intTable.appendRow(row: [1,2,3])

var anyTable = Table<Any>()
anyTable.appendRow(row: ["Hello World", 12])
```

Comment: Of course I can implement my own table and aggregation operations but I tend to avoid reinventing the wheel. Is there any library that already provides this functionality? I'm surprised by that.

Comment: @CarlosVega asking for a tool is off-topic on Stack overflow

Comment: I'm not asking for a tool. I'm asking about the best practice, or library. I'm not saying your answer is a bad answer. Thanks for it by the way.

Comment: @CarlosVega Library recommendations are offtopic too. Best practices are opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has made a framework for this called [TabularData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tabulardata).

It allows you to import & export data from JSON & CSV files as well as programatically storing, sorting and summarising tabular data with simple statistics like element count, maximum, mininum, [mean](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tabulardata/numericsummary/mean), and [standard deviation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tabulardata/numericsummary/standarddeviation).

Note that it only works on iOS 15.0+, macOS 12.0+, tvOS 15.0+, or watchOS 8.0+

Answer (score 0):

You can use SwiftyTextTable: https://github.com/scottrhoyt/SwiftyTextTable.

It is awesome and very easy to use as well. Let's say you can to store data in a table like this.

```
/*
+-----+-----+-----+
| foo | bar | baz |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 1   | 2   | 3   |
| 11  | 22  | 33  |
+-----+-----+-----+
*/
```

Swift code to store this data would be

```
// create columns

let column1 = TextTableColumn(header: "foo")
let column2 = TextTableColumn(header: "bar")
let column3 = TextTableColumn(header: "baz")

// Then create a table with the columns

var table = TextTable(columns: [column1, column2, column3])


// Then add some rows

table.addRow([1, 2, 3])
table.addRow([11, 22, 33])
```

Comment: this does not support mathematical operations, isn't it?

Comment: For Mathematical operations , you can simple make your down extentions  using High order functions.

Comment: Which mathematical operations do you need to support?

Comment: std, mean, sum, median, etc. I could do it myself (my current approach) but I prefer to use matured libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this library: https://github.com/AramKoorn/swifty

To store data in tabular form you can easily create a DataFrame like

```
 var df1 = DataFrame(data: [[1, 2], ["a", "b"]], columns: ["col1", "col2"])
```

If you want to appen data you can use the concat() function. E.g.

```
  var df2 = DataFrame(data: [[3, 4], ["c", "d"]], columns: ["col1", "col2"])
  df1.concat(data: [df2], axis: "rows")
```

output will be:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-0pky{border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0pky">col1</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">col2</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">4</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">d</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```